# Removing completely overlapping intervals or ranges

Tags: awk

Earlier today I saw a - apparently badly formed and therefore already deleted - question about removing overlapping intervals (or ranges, intervals from this on). The question was how to remove intervals which are completely within other intervals. For example, we have the following:

```
1-2
2-3
1-3
2-4
```

or if slightly better visualized:

```
1-2
  2-3
1---3
  2---4
```

Intervals `1-2` and `2-3` are both removed since they are included in the interval `1-3` so the output would be:

```
1-3
2-4
```

*A priori* algorithm would probably be to check every interval against every other resulting in O(n<sup>2</sup>) comparisons. Someone suggested to sort the source data before processing, are there other angles to this problem?

Obvious cases are (data sorted):

```
1-3    remove
1--4

1-3    remove this or next
1-3

1--4
 2-4   remove

1---5
 2-4   remove

1-3    print this, maybe next depending on the one after that
 2-4
```

Please, if you come up with nice pitfalls or other cases in the data or affiliated tags add them.

Answer (score 2):

This solution expects the data to be sorted before processing, as suggested by someone:

```
$ sort -t- -k1n -k2n file  # playin' it safe
1-2
1-3
2-3
2-4
```

In awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN { OFS=FS="-" }
{
    if(p=="") {                     # if p is empty, fill it
        p=$0                        # p is the previous record
        next
    }
    split(p,b,"-")                  # p is split to start and end to b[]

    if(b[1] == $1 && b[2] <= $2) {  # since sorting is expected:
        p=$0                        # if starts are equal p line is included or identical
        next                        # so remove it
    }
    else if($2 <= b[2])             # latter is included
        next

    print p                         # no complete overlap, print p 
    p=$0                            # and to the next
}
END { print p }
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk <(sort -t- -k1n -k2n file)
1-3
2-4
```

or

```
1-2
  2-3
```

Comment: you can avoid splitting by setting `-F-`

Comment: `sort file` will sort alphabetically so `10` will come before `2`, etc. You need something more like `sort -t'-' -k1 -k2 -n file`. Check that as I always get my sort args mixed up but you get the idea you need to sort each part of the range numerically and separately.

Comment: And @karakfa is correct - set `-F'-'` and replace `a[1]` with `$1`, etc. I feel like it could be further simplified without so many "next"s but idk...

Answer (score 1):

As long as the algorithm has polynomial complexity, I think the straightforward solution is ok as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="-";
}
{

    arr[NR][1] = $1;
    arr[NR][2] = $2;
}
END {

    for(i in arr) {

        delete_nxt_elem(i);

        if(arr[i][1]!="")
            print arr[i][1],arr[i][2];
    }
}

function delete_nxt_elem(check_indx,   j) {

    for(j in arr) {

        if(j==check_indx)
            continue;

        if(arr[j][1]<=arr[check_indx][1] && arr[j][2]>=arr[check_indx][2])
            delete arr[check_indx];
    }
}
```